# How to enable output highlighting as xdebug mode?

Tags: php, xdebug

When in my php.php is enable **xdebug** mode, all output constructions as **var_dump** become colorized (red, green colors).

How to enable this colors without xdebug mode?

Answer (score 2):

Every settings is on the [Xdebug settings page](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings).

This is what you need:

```
xdebug.cli_color = 2
```

> xdebug.cli_color
>   Type: integer, Default value: 0, Introduced in Xdebug > 2.2
>   If this setting is 1, Xdebug will color var_dumps and stack traces output when in CLI mode and when the output is a tty. On Windows, the ANSICON tool needs to be installed.
>
> If the setting is 2, then Xdebug will always color var_dumps and stack
>   trace, no matter whether it's connected to a tty or whether ANSICON is
>   installed. In this case, you might end up seeing escape codes.

**UPDATE**

Sadly, ANSICON is no more on that link what xDebug referenced. You can download it from [here](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads).

*Warning:* fo me, the Comodo Internet security is marked the .dll files as a virus, so listen for it.